# Why TargetNullValue cannot be used in x:Bind?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

As [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#properties_you_can_set), *TargetNullValue*:

> Specifies a value to display when the source value resolves but is explicitly null.

With old *Binding* something like this was possible and worked:

```xml
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Something, Converter={StaticResource myconv}, TargetNullValue='Collapsed'}">
```

But it's not possible with `x:Bind` - if we write:

```xml
<Grid Visibility="{x:Bind Something, Converter={StaticResource myconv}, TargetNullValue='Collapsed'}">
```

we will likely get error:

> TargetNullValue cannot be applied on 'Visibility' because its type 'Visibility' is not nullable.

Which for me doesn't make much sense - why is that?

Comment: You have to handle the null value in the converter.

Comment: @TóthTibor Yeah, handling it with converter is what I'm doing already, it just makes *TargetNullValue* useless, as you cannot use it, when it should clearly be possible.

Comment: you can still use Binding in uwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which for me doesn't make much sense - why is that?

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) "`{x:Bind}` lacks some of the features of `{Binding}`" and apparently this is one of them.

Apparently `TargetNullValue` can not be specified for a *value* type target property.

But you could easily handle this in your converter so it should be that much of an issue.

You could always bring this up at the UserVoice if you want to: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, though it doesn't change the fact that it doesn't make sense for me. Nevertheless, I've [posted on UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18521620-remove-type-check-from-x-bind-targetnullvalue).